# How to add a new functionality to a command line arparse menu?

Tags: python

I have a scholar project which is about a command line menu script. It expects a directory with a large text file, for example this is how I execute the program:

```
 project/script.py /large_text_directory
```

So, lets assume I add a new sub directory and a `.txt` file to `/data`, let's say `new_directory/list.txt`:

Now I create this new functionality:

What would be an easy aproach to add the previous functionality to this command line menu.

For example I would like to run the script like this:

```
python project/txt
```

I know this could be difficult but this is my first dive in argparse. How can I aproach this?. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you read the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) documentation? Adding an argument is very simple.

Comment: Yes, I have been reading it but I dont get how to do it. Thanks for the feedback @msvalkon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will store the filename given from commandline to the `opts.sw`.

```
p.add_argument("-sw", action="store", help="Enter a specific file to process")
```

When using this commandline switch, after `opts = p.parse_args()` the contents of `opts.sw` will be `path/of/the/file_1.txt`

After this you'll pass that filename to the function that does your text processing.

Comment: So the new functionality must be "wrapped" in a function?

Comment: Yes, generally you will want your code to be modular. This means splitting functionality in functions, classes and eventually modules and packages.